# COPY ignore blank columns

Tags: amazon-redshift

Unfortunately I've got some huge number of csv files with missing separator as following. Notice the second data got only 1 separator with 2 values. Currently I'm getting "delimiter not found error".

Only if I could insert NULL to 3rd column in case there is only two values.

```
1,avc,99
2,xyz
3,timmy,6
```

Is there anyway I can COPY this files into Redshift without modifying CSV files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `FILLRECORD` parameter to load NULLs for blank columns

You can [check the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-conversion.html#copy-fillrecord) for more details